# How do I initialize or reset dash home settings?

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash

I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, and my dash home has gone blank. This is not a hardware issue, because it works fine if I run Precise in the "try" mode from the install USB stick.

I therefore presume that something in the previous settings carried into 12.04 is causing this glitch. So, if all the settings could be reinitialized the problem should hopefully go away.

Comment: I experience the same bug. In both Unity and Unity-2D, the Dash is blank. No application I search for finds results.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... i believe i suffer from the same issues.

The Blank screen that you are facing as well.

For my case it is unity issue.
I simply cannot get the unity 3d to work correctly.

Ways to get around it, is to use unity 2d. Have you tried that ?
Before login in, just click on the button above your name and select ubuntu2d.
That should do it.

Or you can hit ctrl+alt+f1 and do a `sudo compiz --reset`
Hit ctrl+alt+f7 to get back into your GUI and give it some time, see if unity wakes up.